# Not able to find command prompt after exiting Perl program using exit 0, until I press ENTER

Tags: linux, perl

I have a Perl script which needs to be exited when it receives a USR1 signal, so now I am exiting the Perl script in the `sigtrap{ }` subroutine using `exit 0;`, I am able to exit the process but I am not able to find the command prompt until I press ENTER, after the Perl program exits.

Comment: Which OS (flavor), shell, and versions of these and perl?  Are you able to send a command to the shell before this initial `ENTER` keypress?

Comment: @abiessu Please don't edit the question to change **Perl** to **perl** and **I** to **i**. When referring to the language, always use **Perl**.

Comment: @YuHao: I assume that abiessu started his/her proposed edit before you made yours, so (s)he didn't actively change *Perl* and *I* to *perl* and *i*, but merely didn't preserve your contrary change.

Comment: @YuHao I didn't...  I only modified the code pieces.  For language references, I can do that, although it is sometimes the difference between `perl` the command and Perl the language...

Comment: @abiessu My bad, that explained it. The editing history is misleading.

Comment: @abiessu Flavour of Linux is x86_64 GNU/Linux, Shell Type is csh, Perl Version is 5.8.8

Comment: @abiessu Yes, Iam able to send the command to the shell before the intial ENTER keypress.

Answer (score 0):

without pasting any console output it is mostly guessing but most probably the issue is output of the script. Try running your script like this to see if it makes any difference:

```
perl myscript.pl ; echo ; echo
```

Comment: As a for-instance, a script can output characters that act like the `delete` key to the shell, and thus erase parts of the prompt after they finish.  Adding `echo` after a script is like pressing `enter` after the script has finished.